# Ember-CLI: include app file in Brocfile.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

I have a config setting I'd like to include in Brocfile.js, so that I don't set it in the file directly. For example, in **config/custom.js** I would have something like:

```
export default {
  path: 'http://abc.blah.com/'
};
```

In my Brocfile, I'd like to do something like:

```
if (process.env.EMBER_ENV === 'development') {
  app.options.inlineContent = {
    assetPrefix: {
      content: customConfig.path
    }
  };
}
```

How do I import/include **custom.js** in my Brocfile, and use its **path** property? I tried importing, but get:

```
import config from 'config/custom.js';
^^^^^^
Unexpected reserved word
```

UPDATE:

Based on the answer below, here's what my files ended up looking like:

```
// config/custom.js

module.exports = {
  assetPrependPath: 'http://abc.blah.com/'
};


// Brocfile.js

var customConfig = require('./config/custom');

...

if (process.env.EMBER_ENV === 'development') {
  app.options.inlineContent = {
    assetPrefix: {
      content:  customConfig.assetPrependPath
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because `Brocfile.js` is not parsed by the ES6 parser. This is because the Brocfile is not in your app's tree (the app directory). Therefore, you cannot use syntax like `import` in the Brocfile.

Your Brocfile is used for building the application. Environment specific variables like those you're setting inside `if (process.env.EMBER_ENV === 'development')` should go in Ember CLI's `config/environment.js` file. Any properties in the `environment.js`'s `ENV.APP` object are passed to your application instance and addons. Thus, depending on your end goal, you may be able to take that approach and have no need to import into the Brocfile.

If you really want to import something into your Brocfile you will need to use a module loader like require.js:

```
var Config = require('path/to/config.js');`
```

... And then in you `path/to/config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  // Options here
}
```

#### Asset Revision

Looking at your use case you might want to look at a Broccoli addon like [broccoli-asset-rev](https://github.com/rickharrison/broccoli-asset-rev) to do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, doing a **require** for a file inside the app directory throws a **Cannot find module** error. And using the **broccoli-asset-rev** add-on doesn't help the issue at hand. I'm using a similar component already, and need to be able to insert a variable instead of hard-coded values.

Comment: The file you're trying to import using require has to use the correct module syntax in it (note - not ES6 module syntax). Usually this means defining an object as `module.exports` in the file at `path/to/config.js`. Then you should be able to import it with no problem - in fact Ember CLI does this in the Brocfile blueprint. What version of Ember CLI are you using?

Comment: I will try to change the syntax of my config file. As you can see in the question, currently I am using ES6 module syntax. I am on Ember-CLI 0.1.7.

Comment: Using **module.exports** did the trick. If you update your answer to include that bit, I will accept it.